# Balance security with performance in android notebook app

Tags: android, security

As a notebook product, the user's sensitive data should be encrypted before stored in the database, in case the Android phone was root, and the database file was stolen by another evil  app.

But in that case, search in the notebook would be slow, because the app has to decrypt every notes before searching.

How to balance security with performance in this case?

Comment: Can you encrypt your search request and look over encrypted data? During one SQL request you encrypt only your request and decrypt all matched results, but not all rowas in Database.

Comment: @Borys Good advice, any encrypt algorithm can do that? Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep your database encrypted and at the same time keep it very responsive, you could use [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/). Taken from their description: "*SQLCipher is an SQLite extension that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files*"